# nifi expression concat text in filename

Tags: apache-nifi

I have created a RouteOnAttribute processor in nifi dataflow, i want it to select only certain files to parse on. 
in the properties i have created a property "filetofetch" 
with following expression

```
${filename:contains('INCOMING.D151221')
```

I need to fetch the file name INCOMING.D< YYYYMMDD>
so today 21 MARTS 2017 the filename would be

```
INCOMING.D20170321
```

I have tried with something like this to extraxt file name

```
${filename:contains('INCOMING.D'+ ${now():format('yyyymmdd')} )}
```

But i cannot concat with the date prefix 
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Havmaage,

You can concat by use append in Expression language like below.,

You have to use the updateAttribute to store the 'Incoming.D' in one attribute name like below.

```
   fileStartsWith:Incoming.D
   Date:${now():format('yyyyMMdd')
```

Then finally  use routeonattribute to check like below.

```
    ${filename:contains(${fileStartsWith:append(${date})})}
```

You cann't be concat with '+' in Nifi.

**EDIT-1:**

```
  Date:${now():format('yyyyMMdd')
```

Comment: Ok, i still not getting match,

Comment: Ok, i still not getting match, my flowfile name is INCOMING.D170321 and my UpdateAttribute is condition ${filename:contains('INCOMING')} attribute Date ${now():format('yymmdd') attribute FileStartWtih ${now():format('yymmdd') in RouteONAttribute my expression is ${filename:contains(${FileStartWith:append(${Date})})} what exatly does ${now():format('yymmdd') i would exspect it to be 170321

Comment: FilesStarWith Attribute has following value  'INCOMING.D'

Comment: Can you check my EDIT-1?you have specified month in 'mm' that's the problem for issue.If you change that like 'MM' then it should work.